# How to monitor jar file running in Windows Server using Nagios

Tags: java, jar, jvm, nagios, server-monitoring

I want to monitor a jar file running in a Windows Server.Currently i am executing jar file in command line.NsClient is installed in windows server.Can anyone help on this

Comment: What's the problem you meet?

Comment: how can i mointor that whether a jar file is running or not

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin using [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html):

```
jps | find /C "your jar"
```

If it's running it will return 1+, if not, 0.